# SSIS generating csv file without headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I’m making an SSIS package to create a CSV file using `OLE DB Source` and `Flat File Destination`.

When I get the file it doesn't contain the headers but they are clearly defined in the destination.

I've tried all the options related to this:

- headers rows to skip -1,
- column names in the first data row,
- column delimiter,
- data rows to skip
- and even resetting the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the option in the Flat file connection manager as [image: below]

Just in case this doesn't work then the setting are not being carried over to your config files. In such cases there are two workarounds:

1. Editing the .dtconfig to edit "firstcolumnhasnames" to 1 adds the column names without needing to delete the connection from the package.
2. delete the destination connection, and recreate from scratch.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried that option but then picks the first row with values. I have tried to rebuild that several times as well. About .dtconfig.. where is this file? I didn't see it in the project folder, do I need to create it?

Comment: I've created the file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx but couldn't find the option if anyone has the same problem: http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/01/ssis-2012-package-configurations-menu-option-missing/

Comment: I've modified the .dtsconfig and it worked! thank you very much.